# Python - Compatibility Issues between Shapely and Geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am attempting to run shapely.ops and my kernel dies. I believe this is due to version controls between GeoPandas and Shapely but am unable to figure out the issues.

For more information, note that my kernel dies when running this line:

```
import shapely
merged = vertical_stack.groupby('name').geometry.agg(shapely.ops.unary_union)
```

The item that I am attempting to aggregate and dissolve is a geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame

For version of modules, see below:

```
pip list

Package                            Version
---------------------------------- ----------------------
affine                             2.3.0
aiohttp                            3.7.3
alabaster                          0.7.12
anaconda-client                    1.7.2
anaconda-navigator                 1.9.12
anaconda-project                   0.8.3
applaunchservices                  0.2.1
appnope                            0.1.0
appscript                          1.1.1
area                               1.1.1
argh                               0.26.2
arrow                              0.17.0
asgiref                            3.3.1
asn1crypto                         1.3.0
astroid                            2.4.2
astropy                            4.0.1.post1
async-timeout                      3.0.1
atomicwrites                       1.4.0
attrs                              19.3.0
autopep8                           1.5.3
Babel                              2.8.0
backcall                           0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.6.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
backports.tempfile                 1.0
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4                     4.9.1
bitarray                           1.4.0
bkcharts                           0.2
bleach                             3.1.5
bokeh                              2.1.1
boto                               2.49.0
Bottleneck                         1.3.2
branca                             0.4.1
brotlipy                           0.7.0
cairocffi                          1.2.0
CairoSVG                           2.5.2
census                             0.8.15
CensusData                         1.10
certifi                            2020.6.20
cffi                               1.14.0
chardet                            3.0.4
click                              7.1.2
click-plugins                      1.1.1
cligj                              0.5.0
cloudpickle                        1.5.0
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.4.3
conda                              4.10.1
conda-build                        3.18.11
conda-package-handling             1.7.0+0.g7c4a471.dirty
conda-verify                       3.4.2
configparser                       5.0.2
contextlib2                        0.6.0.post1
crayons                            0.4.0
cryptography                       2.9.2
cssselect2                         0.4.1
cycler                             0.10.0
Cython                             0.29.21
cytoolz                            0.10.1
dask                               2.20.0
dataframe-image                    0.1.1
decorator                          4.4.2
defusedxml                         0.6.0
descartes                          1.1.0
diff-match-patch                   20200713
distributed                        2.20.0
Django                             3.1.7
docopt                             0.2.0
docopt-ng                          0.7.2
docopt-plus                        0.6.3a1
docutils                           0.16
entrypoints                        0.3
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1
fastcache                          1.1.0
filelock                           3.0.12
Fiona                              1.8.17
flake8                             3.8.3
Flask                              1.1.2
folium                             0.0.0
fpdf                               1.7.2
fsspec                             0.7.4
future                             0.18.2
fuzzymatcher                       0.0.5
fuzzywuzzy                         0.18.0
GDAL                               3.1.3
geographiclib                      1.50
geojson                            2.5.0
geomet                             0.2.1.post1
geopandas                          0.9.0
geopy                              2.1.0
geoutils                           0.0.1
gevent                             20.6.2
glob2                              0.7
gmpy2                              2.0.8
greenlet                           0.4.16
h3                                 3.7.0
h5py                               2.10.0
HeapDict                           1.0.1
html5lib                           1.1
idna                               2.5
image                              1.5.33
imageio                            2.9.0
imagesize                          1.2.0
importlib-metadata                 1.7.0
intervaltree                       3.0.2
ipykernel                          5.3.2
ipython                            7.16.1
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0
ipywidgets                         7.5.1
isort                              4.3.21
itsdangerous                       1.1.0
jdcal                              1.4.1
jedi                               0.17.1
jellyfish                          0.6.1
Jinja2                             2.11.2
jinja2-time                        0.2.0
joblib                             0.16.0
json5                              0.9.5
jsonschema                         3.2.0
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     6.1.6
jupyter-console                    6.1.0
jupyter-core                       4.6.3
jupyterlab                         2.1.5
jupyterlab-server                  1.2.0
keplergl                           0.2.1
keyring                            21.2.1
kiwisolver                         1.2.0
lazy-object-proxy                  1.4.3
libarchive-c                       2.9
libpysal                           4.4.0
llvmlite                           0.33.0+1.g022ab0f
locket                             0.2.0
lxml                               4.5.2
make                               0.1.6.post2
MarkupSafe                         1.1.1
matplotlib                         3.3.2
mccabe                             0.6.1
Metaphone                          0.6
mistune                            0.8.4
mkl-fft                            1.1.0
mkl-random                         1.1.1
mkl-service                        2.3.0
mock                               4.0.2
more-itertools                     8.4.0
mplleaflet                         0.0.5
mpmath                             1.1.0
msgpack                            1.0.0
multidict                          5.1.0
multipledispatch                   0.6.0
munch                              2.5.0
navigator-updater                  0.2.1
nbconvert                          5.6.1
nbformat                           5.0.7
networkx                           2.5
nltk                               3.5
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           6.0.3
numba                              0.50.1
numexpr                            2.7.1
numpy                              1.19.2
numpydoc                           1.1.0
objectpath                         0.6.1
olefile                            0.46
openpyxl                           3.0.4
orca                               1.5.4
osm2geojson                        0.1.29
osmnx                              0.16.1
OSMPythonTools                     0.2.9
osmtogeojson                       0.0.2
overpass                           0.7
overpassify                        1.2.2
overpy                             0.4
packaging                          20.4
pandas                             1.1.3
pandocfilters                      1.4.2
parso                              0.7.0
partd                              1.1.0
path                               13.1.0
pathlib2                           2.3.5
pathtools                          0.1.2
patsy                              0.5.1
pep8                               1.7.1
pexpect                            4.8.0
pickleshare                        0.7.5
Pillow                             7.2.0
pip                                20.1.1
pkginfo                            1.5.0.1
plotly                             4.14.3
pluggy                             0.13.1
ply                                3.11
prometheus-client                  0.8.0
prompt-toolkit                     3.0.5
psutil                             5.7.0
ptyprocess                         0.6.0
py                                 1.9.0
pycodestyle                        2.6.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.20
pycurl                             7.43.0.5
pydocstyle                         5.0.2
pyflakes                           2.2.0
pygeos                             0.10
pyGeoTile                          1.0.6
Pygments                           2.6.1
pylint                             2.5.3
pyodbc                             4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL                          19.1.0
pyparsing                          2.4.7
Pyphen                             0.10.0
pyproj                             2.6.1.post1
pyrsistent                         0.16.0
PySocks                            1.7.1
pytest                             5.4.3
pytest-sugar                       0.9.4
python-dateutil                    2.8.1
python-dotenv                      0.14.0
python-jsonrpc-server              0.3.4
python-language-server             0.34.1
python-Levenshtein                 0.12.0
PyTrie                             0.4.0
pytz                               2020.1
PyWavelets                         1.1.1
PyYAML                             5.3.1
pyzmq                              19.0.1
q                                  2.6
QDarkStyle                         2.8.1
QtAwesome                          0.7.2
qtconsole                          4.7.5
QtPy                               1.9.0
queuelib                           1.5.0
rasterio                           1.2.5
regex                              2020.6.8
requests                           2.25.1
retrying                           1.3.3
rope                               0.17.0
Rtree                              0.9.4
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.87
scikit-image                       0.16.2
scikit-learn                       0.23.1
scipy                              1.5.0
seaborn                            0.10.1
selenium                           3.141.0
Send2Trash                         1.5.0
setuptools                         49.2.0.post20200714
Shapely                            1.7.1
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
simplejson                         3.17.2
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3
six                                1.15.0
snowballstemmer                    2.0.0
snuggs                             1.4.7
sortedcollections                  1.2.1
sortedcontainers                   2.2.2
soupsieve                          2.0.1
Sphinx                             3.1.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp            1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp              1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp             1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath               1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp               1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml      1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.2.3
spyder                             4.1.4
spyder-kernels                     1.9.2
SQLAlchemy                         1.3.18
sqlparse                           0.4.1
statsmodels                        0.11.1
sympy                              1.6.1
tables                             3.6.1
tabulate                           0.8.7
tblib                              1.6.0
termcolor                          1.1.0
terminado                          0.8.3
testpath                           0.4.4
threadpoolctl                      2.1.0
tile-comparator                    2.2.1
tinycss2                           1.1.0
toml                               0.10.1
toolz                              0.10.0
tornado                            6.0.4
tqdm                               4.47.0
traitlets                          4.3.3
traittypes                         0.2.1
typing-extensions                  3.7.4.2
ujson                              1.35
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
universities                       1.1.0
university-scraper                 0.0.2
urllib3                            1.21.1
us                                 2.0.2
validators                         0.14.0
watchdog                           0.10.3
wcwidth                            0.2.5
WeasyPrint                         52.5
webdriver-manager                  3.3.0
webencodings                       0.5.1
Werkzeug                           1.0.1
wheel                              0.34.2
widgetsnbextension                 3.5.1
wrapt                              1.11.2
wurlitzer                          2.0.1
xarray                             0.16.2
xcode                              0.0.1
xlrd                               1.2.0
XlsxWriter                         1.2.9
xlwings                            0.19.5
xlwt                               1.3.0
xmltodict                          0.12.0
yapf                               0.30.0
yarl                               1.6.3
zict                               2.0.0
zipp                               3.1.0
zope.event                         4.4
zope.interface                     4.7.1
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `dissolve` method?

Comment: You're right. I was able to achieve the desired results with dissolve

Comment: FWIW in the past I've experienced the kernel dying if I used shapely.ops on pygeos geometries (ie, geopandas configured to use the pygeos back end).